# Check linearity Residual vs Fitted Chart

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, diagnostic

I have a question about one of the simple linear regression test graphs. Looking at the graph it apparently appears to be linear but this curve is causing me a lot of doubt, I did another test that I found, the Ramsey RESET test and the result showed that there are no statements of non-linearity, however, this curve left me in doubt.

[image: residual vs fitted]

Comment: I think, except for the small bulb, the plot does look fairly linear. Your sample size also doesn't seem to be very big, so that may cause some small deviations. I would suggest to indeed also base your conclusion on tests and if they indicate no sign of non-linearity as you say, just stick with linearity. Either way, just report this deviation/concern in your report to make the reader aware of this.

Comment: It's not linearity that is the reference, but being a flat line in particular. I agree that you can't expect a flat smooth with a small sample size. I disagree that formal testing is the way to go; the main point is that really strong curvature or other features should leap out at you; absence of pattern does not imply absence of problems, but no news is good news.

Comment: If you lack experience with interpreting these plots, I recommend to simulate data of the same sample size with residuals from a normal distribution and compare plots from this simulated data with the plot from your measured data. (You might find the DHARMa package useful. It provides a nice framework based on such simulations.)